# How to represent an array as a procedure

Tags: procedure, pascal

```
uses GraphABC;
var 
  x, y: integer;

  procedure kv(x, y: integer; color: system.Drawing.Color);
  begin
    Rectangle(x, y, x + 20, y - 50);
    FloodFill(x + 10, y - 10, color);
  end;

  procedure DrawPyramid(arr: array of array [1..2] of integer);
  begin
    for var i := 1 to Length(arr) do
    begin
      kv(arr[i][1], arr[i][2], clRed);
    end;
  end;

  var arr: array of array [1..2] of integer;

begin
  SetPenColor(clBlack);
  kv(40, 50, clGreen);
  x := 80;  
  y := 100;
  SetLength(arr, 4);

  for var i := 1 to 3 do
  begin
    arr[i][1] := x - 20 * i;
    arr[i][2] := y;
  end;

  x := 120;
  y := 150;
  SetLength(arr, 9);

  for var i := 4 to 8 do
  begin
    arr[i][1] := x - 20 * (i-3);
    arr[i][2] := y;
  end;

  for var i := 1 to 3 do
  begin 
    kv(arr[i][1], arr[i][2], clOrange);
  end;

  for var i := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    arr[i][1] := x - 20 * (i+1);
    arr[i][2] := y;
    kv(arr[i][1], arr[i][2], clRed);
  end;

end.
```

I don't understand how to correctly insert an array representing a pyramid into a procedure (not a "kv" procedure) with which I will perform operations in the future, for example, to copy a pyramid.

I looked at several options from the Internet, but still did not understand how to technically represent an array in my code in the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for (although your question is somewhat unclear).

```
uses GraphABC;
type
  TTwoDimArray = array of array[1..2] of integer;
var 
  x, y: integer;

  procedure kv(x, y: integer; color: system.Drawing.Color);
  begin
    Rectangle(x, y, x + 20, y - 50);
    FloodFill(x + 10, y - 10, color);
  end;

  procedure DrawPyramid(arr: TTwoDimArray);
  begin
    for var i := 1 to Length(arr) do
    begin
      kv(arr[i][1], arr[i][2], clRed);
    end;
  end;

var 
  arr: TTwoDimArray;

begin
  SetPenColor(clBlack);
  kv(40, 50, clGreen);
  x := 80;  
  y := 100;
  SetLength(arr, 4);

  for var i := 1 to 3 do
  begin
    arr[i][1] := x - 20 * i;
    arr[i][2] := y;
  end;

  x := 120;
  y := 150;
  SetLength(arr, 9);

  for var i := 4 to 8 do
  begin
    arr[i][1] := x - 20 * (i-3);
    arr[i][2] := y;
  end;

  for var i := 1 to 3 do
  begin 
    kv(arr[i][1], arr[i][2], clOrange);
  end;

  for var i := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    arr[i][1] := x - 20 * (i+1);
    arr[i][2] := y;
    kv(arr[i][1], arr[i][2], clRed);
  end;

end.
```